# Python/Splinter: How to find and select an option on a site?

Tags: python, python-2.7, browser, splinter

Using Python and Splinter, currently, I need to define exactly what text, `option1` to click on when an option is found on a page:

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser('chrome')

browser.find_option_by_text(option1).first.click()
```

But if the `option1` is not there, how can I fall back and choose any next option available rather than having to define it?

And is it possible to just find an option on a page and choose any first, available option encountered, without having to define the option?

Thank you in advance and will be sure to upvote/accept answer

Comment: Years ago I used mechanize library to do such thing. My python skills are a bit dust right now though.

Comment: @BurakKaanKöse If you ever get around to it, would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

You could get all the options in the page. So if the first search for `option1` is empty, you can resume to the next options available.

```
selected_option = browser.find_option_by_text(option1) or browser.find_by_tag('option')
selected_option = selected_option.first if selected_option else None
```

The inline `if` in the second line is there because the `find_by_tag` can also return an empty list if there are no options at all in that page.

The `find_by_tag` method is the response for both questions, since you can use it as a fallback or collect all the options at once.